How do I design a USB interface to program a custom microcontroller?
I am trying to design a microcontroller board that I can program over USB (like an Arduino). I would like to use the STM32L412KBU3, and going through the data sheet I see that USB_DM and USB_DP are on pins PA11 and PA12. Simply connecting those pins to a female USB port seems too easy and I feel like there must be something I'm missing. I've been running through the datasheet and user manual for any explicit information on how to design this type of interface. I would really appreciate information on how to get this done.
Thanks

Look at the eval board schematic

You are not missing anything.
That MCU has a built-in USB interface.
And that microcontroller already has a factory bootloader which allows to program it via USB.
All you need to do is to make it boot into the factory bootloader, for example by pushing a button while powering the MCU or resetting it. Of course it may need a certain environment to use the USB interface like a suitable supply voltage range or a suitable crystal frequency.

Alright, I'll try it out, Thanks for the response :)
